# How can I properly make a generic type of another generic type in java?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, casting

I have many classes that include each other like such: a `Project` contains many `Tab`s, each of which contain many `Item`s.

`Item`s' hierarchy is pretty straightforward:

```java
abstract Item
  abstract FooItem extends Item
    FooAItem extends FooItem
    FooBItem extends FooItem
  abstract BarItem extends Item
    BarAItem extends BarItem
    BarBItem extends BarItem
```

`Tab`s need to know what type of `Item`s they can contain:

```java
abstract Tab<ITEM extends Item>
  abstract FooTab<ITEM extends FooItem> extends Tab<ITEM>
    FooATab extends FooTab<FooAItem>
    FooBTab extends FooTab<FooBItem>
  abstract BarTab<ITEM extends BarItem> extends Tab<ITEM>
    BarATab extends BarTab<BarAItem>
    BarBTab extends BarTab<BarBItem>
```

So far, I'm good. It becomes tricky when I add the `Project` layer which only has 1 generic implementation (and I can't create more specific implementations because of legacy code):

```java
Project<ITEM extends Item, TAB extends Tab<ITEM>>
```

Now the type of `Tab` becomes linked to the type of `Item`. So in my code, when I use a variable of type, let's say, `Project<FooItem, FooTab<FooItem>>`, I can't write a method `project.getTab(id)` that could be called like:

```java
FooATab fooATab = project.getTab(id);
```

Because the resulting type does not cast to the generic type `TAB extends Tab<ITEM>` where `ITEM` is `FooItem` and not the `FooAItem` specified in the signature of FooATab.

Here's some partial implementation of `Project` as of today:

```java
public class Project<ITEM extends Item, TAB extends Tab<ITEM>> {

    private final SortedSet<TAB> tabs;

    public <T extends TAB> T getTab(final int id) {
        return this.tabs.stream()
                          .filter(t -> id == t.getId())
                          .findAny()
                          .map(a -> (T) a)
                          .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

(I also get an unchecked cast from TAB to T warning, but that's kinda expected).

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: In getTab, I don't know that there's any way you can know at compile time what type the returning tab you will have - it looks like that's kind of a feature of getTab. But in any case, you can't do this with generics (as you are trying)

Comment: If you want to get a `FooATab` from the project, why not use `Project<FooAItem, FooATab>`? Because with the current generic type, it's possible that the project contains `FooBTab` elements. That's a `ClassCastException` waiting to happen - the unchecked cast warning is there for a reason.

Comment: The thing is, I know there will be both `FooATab`s and `FooBTab`s in my `Project` but they will always be associated to the same id (legacy code as I said) so `ClassCastException` should not be a problem, but I can't type my project more precisely, hence the `Project<FooItem, FooTab<FooItem>>`